# How to update bunch of data with Event Sourcing

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I wondering how to update bunch of data in Event Sourcing concept for any aggregate.

In traditional application I would take some data such as name, date of birth etc. and put them into existing object; as I understand, in ES concept this approach is wrong, **so that should I perform different Events to update different parts of aggregate root? If so, that how to build REST API? How to handle with validation?**

Comment: This question is overly broad. What have you tried? What specifically about the REST API is it that you are having trouble with? What have you read about validation when using ES or CQRS and what are the questions therein?

Answer (score 2):

> In traditional application I would take some data such as name, date of birth etc. and put them into existing object; as I understand, in ES concept this approach is wrong,

Short answer: that approach is fine -- what changes in event sourcing is how you keep track of the changes in your service.

A way to think of a stream of events is a sequence of patch-documents.  There's nothing wrong with changing multiple fields in a single patch document, and that is fine in events as well.

Comment: With update, isn't we lose the versioning of the data? If ES is appending only store, than update is breaking the rules, even if we know the id of the uniquely column for every update request that will exists in the system.

Like every system where nothing goes by the plan it's ok to have update just in case, we like to use brute force for something.

Answer (score 1):

This question is really too broad for SO.  You should google “event sourcing basics in azure” to find detailed articles, github projects, videos, and other responses to these questions.

In general, in Event Sourcing there two main ideas you need – Messages and Events.  A typical process (not the only option, but a common one) is as follows. A message is created by your UI which makes a request for a change to be made to an AR.  Validation for that message is done on the message creation source.

The message is then sent to an API, where it is validated again since you can't trust all possible senders.  The request is processed, resulting in changes made to an AR.  An event is then created describing the changes made, and that event is placed on an event source (Azure Event Hub, Kafka, Kinesis, a DB, whatever). This list of events is kept forever and describes each and every change made to that AR throughout time, including the initial creation request.  To get the current state of the AR, just add up all the events.

The key idea that is confusing when learning Event Sourcing is the two different types of “events”.  Messages ask for a change to be made, Events record that a change has been made.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered, the batch update approach is fine.

I suggest to focus on the event consumption code. If all you have in your ReadSide is a complete aggregate representation, then generic *_UPDATED event is ok.

But if you do have parts of you system interested only in particular part of your aggregate, you might want to update that part separately, so that system doesn't have to analyze all events and dig for particular data.

For example, some demographic analysis system is only interested in the birthdate. It would be much easier for this system to have a BURTHDATE_SET event that it would listen to, and ignore all others.

Fine grained events like this also reduces coupling, because require less knowledge of the internal event data structure.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like you still have an active record way of looking at things.
You should model the *things that happen to your entity* as events rather than the impact of things happening.

So to my mind all of that data might be gathered in a "Person was registered" event but an "Address added" event might also exist - in which case your single command might end up appending two events to the event stream.